# JQuery Form Plugin with multiple submit buttons

Tags: jquery

I'm using the JQuery Form Plugin (http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) to create an Ajax Form.

I am trying put two submit buttons to handle Form Submit and Form Save operations. I need to submit to two different urls depending on the operation I want to perform: Submit or Save.

I'm not very sure how I can get the value of the actual submit button that was clicked, and then submit the form via AJAX based on this information. I need a little help with this.

For the record, I'm using code syntax similar to what is listed below (this is not the actual code):

```
// prepare Options Object 
var options = { 
    target:     '#divToUpdate', 
    url:        'comment.php', 
    success:    function() { 
        alert('Thanks for your comment!'); 
    } 
}; 

// pass options to ajaxForm 
$('#myForm').ajaxForm(options);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I probably didn't research this thoroughly before posting. My apologies.

I did this to sort it out (this is a code sample):

```
var $_ = jQuery;

var options_1 = { 
   target:     '#divToUpdate1', 
   url:        'submit.php'
}; 

var options_2 = { 
   target:     '#divToUpdate2', 
   url:        'save.php'
}; 

$_(document).ready(function() { 
    $_("#id_submitbutton").click(function(){
       $_("#form_id").ajaxForm(options_1);
    });
    $_("#id_savebutton").click(function(){
       $_("#form_id").ajaxForm(options_2);
    });
});
```

Thanks Lalit, I think you were closer to what I needed to do.

Cheers.

Comment: what do `options_1` and `options_2` mean ? How do you get the clicked button name in ajax parameter ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed I updated the answer for clarification. `options_1` and `options_2` are merely individual objects that will be used depending on what button is clicked i.e. either 'Save' or 'Submit' buttons. In this case, the clicked button name is not relevant, but you can get it using the `this` reference [used inside the click function callback] e.g. `this.getAttribute('name')` or `this.name`.

Answer (score 1):

use normal button and check which button is clicked(by checking value property), then submit the form manually.........

Answer (score 0):

Attach the js to both the buttons and in the js do the form submission based on url

```
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>  
  <script type="text/javascript">  
  $(function() {  
    $("#submit").click(function() {  

    }  
}  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but I had this exact same problem and found a better solution than those posted here. In this case you should use `ajaxSubmit` instead of `ajaxForm`. You need control over the form, so you need to give up control over the submit buttons only.

```
$('#button1').click(function() { 
    // submit the form 
    $('#form').ajaxSubmit(options1); 
});
$('#button2').click(function() { 
    // submit the form 
    $('#form').ajaxSubmit(options2); 
});
```

Sure, you can use `ajaxForm` in this exact same way but that is an unnecessary overkill.

Comment: what do `options_1` and `options_2` mean ? How do you get the clicked button name in ajax parameter ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed Options are the same as is for ajaxForm. You can add the button name as data if you want. http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#options-object